# Time and Date running on page

Tags: javascript, html

Having issue with onload event, its not starting the Javascript on page.

I have tried using following code: `onload="startTime()"` and `document.getElementById("clockdate").onload = function() {startTime()};`

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hr = today.getHours();
  var min = today.getMinutes();
  var sec = today.getSeconds();
  ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>AM</span>" : "<span>PM</span>";
  hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
  hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
  //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
  hr = checkTime(hr);
  min = checkTime(min);
  sec = checkTime(sec);
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ap;

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
  var curDay = today.getDate();
  var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
  var curYear = today.getFullYear();
  var date = curWeekDay + ", " + curMonth + " " + curDay + " " + curYear;
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;

  var time = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdate" onload="startTime()">
  <div id="clock"></div>
  <div id="date"></div>
</div>
```

Trying to show the current time and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) doesnt works with `div`. Try

`document.body.onload = startTime;`

**Shorter version**

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    weekday: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  });
  
  document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = today.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')

  var time = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

document.body.onload = startTime;
```

```html
<div id="clockdate">
  <div id="clock"></div>
  <div id="date"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onload` does not run on div elements: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp
You need to set it on `<body>`

Then, once you get it running, do mind the quality of your code: from a helicopter view, I see a globalscope `ap` variable; also, there is no reason to create an endless chain of closures by recursively calling `setTimeout`; you can achieve the same effect with an external `setInterval` call... If you use `setTimeout`, at least get rid of the useless closure and call `setTimeout(startTime,500)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your data Function is ok slightly. but calling point of functions is wrong try to do what i did.

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hr = today.getHours();
  var min = today.getMinutes();
  var sec = today.getSeconds();
  ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>AM</span>" : "<span>PM</span>";
  hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
  hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
  //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
  hr = checkTime(hr);
  min = checkTime(min);
  sec = checkTime(sec);
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ap;

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
  var curDay = today.getDate();
  var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
  var curYear = today.getFullYear();
  var date = curWeekDay + ", " + curMonth + " " + curDay + " " + curYear;
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;

  var time = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="clockdate">
  <div id="clock"></div>
  <div id="date"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My framework that I am using does not give me access to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: then call ```startTime()``` inside the  ```document.ready(function (){ startTime();}``` like this

Answer (score 0):

```js
function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var hr = today.getHours();
        var min = today.getMinutes();
        var sec = today.getSeconds();
        ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>AM</span>" : "<span>PM</span>";
        hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
        hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
        //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
        hr = checkTime(hr);
        min = checkTime(min);
        sec = checkTime(sec);
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ap;

        var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
        var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
        var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
        var curDay = today.getDate();
        var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
        var curYear = today.getFullYear();
        var date = curWeekDay + ", " + curMonth + " " + curDay + " " + curYear;
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;

        var time = setTimeout(function() {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="clockdate">
        <div id="clock"></div>
        <div id="date"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You have done everything right (just you have to start the function of body `<body onload="startTime()">`

Comment: My framework that I am using does not give me access to the `<body>` tag.